# How to get cell size of GridBagLayout

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I need to place a circle at the center of a GridBagLayout grid. How can I find the current cell width and height?

```
int center = (int) (  ((double) BoardSize / Num/2) - ((double) size/2.0) );
g.fillOval(center, center, size, size);
```

At the moment I am using the size of the containing Frame (BroadSize), but I want to add other elements to GridBag that would make it confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the cell size.

You need to use an appropriate component that will center itself in the space available. You may need to override the `setAlignmentX()` and `setAlignmentY()` values of you custom component. Of course this approach also assume you have overridden the `getPreferredSize()` method of your component properly.

The easiest way is to just use a JLabel with an Icon. See [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for an easy way to do this.

Comment: Problem is that I need the circle to be of a fixed size relative to the cell. So circle in cellA must have diameter of 80% cellA width, and circle in cellB must have diameter of 50% cellB Width. Does not matter what the actual sizes are - as long as circle in cellA and CellB  maintain their relative size difference.

Comment: @ManInMoon, then you can try to make sure the you use the "fill" constraint on the component. Then in you painting you can use the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods of your components. These values should reflect the current size of the component being filled in the cell.